# Iterator Time complexity for a LinkedList in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, time-complexity

The code below will be calling the iterator and sending the integer back to the method it was called from. I just wanted to know if by using an `Iterator` would my time complexity become constant? (i.e O(1)). Because if I use a get with a `LinkedList`, it will give me linear time(i.e O(n)).

```
protected int least(int i) {
    if(i >= digits.size()) {
        return 0;           
    }

    // temp++;
    // System.out.println("Time taken=" + temp);
    // long start = System.nanoTime();

    ListIterator<Integer> itr1 = digits.listIterator(digits.size() - i);

    // System.out.println("Time elapsed:" + (System.nanoTime() - start));

    return itr1.previous();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Iterator starting at i-th element

If you create an `Iterator` which directly starts at the `i`-th index of a `LinkedList`, you need to know that this also takes `O(n)`. Finding an element in a `LinkedList` is always *slow*.

`LinkedList` does **only memorize** the `head` (and `tail`) element of the list. Every other element needs to be found by **traversing the whole list**.

Here is an illustration of a **doubly** linked list (Javas `LinkedList` is also doubly linked):

[image: Structure of LinkedList]

So if you create an `Iterator` starting at the `i`-th element, it will start at `head` (or `tail`) and follow the pointers up to the `i`-th element. It is like calling:

```
list.get(i);
```

This obviously costs `O(n)`.

---

### Alternative: ArrayList

If you need a fast **index-based access**, also called **random-access**, you may consider using an `ArrayList` instead. Its structure allows access in `O(1)` (it can directly compute the position of the element in the memory by `start + i * sizeof(type)`).

Data-structures that provide such a fast random-access usually implement the interface `RandomAccess` ([documentation and implementing classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html)) as indicator.

---

### How to iterate

Iterating a `LinkedList` should, as said, not be done by index-based access via `list.get(i)`. You should therefore use an `Iterator` (or `ListIterator` if you need to modify the list while iterating).

Here is the usual approach using an `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<E> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    E element = iter.next();
    ...
}
```

Or you can also use the **enhanced for-loop** which internally does the same, but looks more compact:

```
for (E element : list) {
    ...
}
```

As Javas `LinkedList` is a **doubly-linked list** you can also start from the **tail** and iterate the list **reversely**. Therefore just use the `LinkedList#descendingIterator` method ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#descendingIterator--)) instead of `LinkedList#iterator`.

Finally an example that shows how to use `ListIterator` to modify the list while iterating:

```
ListIterator<E> listIter = list.listIterator(0);
while (listIter.hasNext()) {
    E element = listIter.next();
    ...
    // Remove the element last polled
    listIter.remove();
    // Inserts an element right before the last polled element
    listIter.add(new Element());
}
```

You can also traverse the list forwards and backwards with `ListIterator` by using `hasPrevious()` and `previous()` methods. Here is its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add-E-).

Comment: Java has marker interface `RandomAccess` which indicates whether a data structure is safe to call `get(index)` from performance point of view.

Comment: Iterator<Integer> itr1 = digits.descendingIterator(); // O(1)
a=itr1.next(); // O(1)
digits.removeLast(); // O(1) ? Will this be removing from the tail?

Comment: `digits.removeLast()` already removes the last element in `O(1)`. No need to call that `Iterator` stuff before. This works since it is a **doubly linked list**, thus the reference to the last element is always available in the `LinkedList`. For removing all elements backwards, you could do: `while (!list.isEmpty()) list.removeLast()`.

Comment: What's the running time of `listIter.remove()`?

Comment: @AnnaVopureta It depends. It does not need to locate the item again, so thats good. For an `ArrayList` it has to shift all elements to the right one to the left, so `O(n)`. For a `LinkedList` it is obviously instant, so `O(1)`, as it just has to adjust the `prev` and `next` pointers of the neighboring nodes. So it is the running time of the data-structures `remove` method, minus the part where it would need to find the element first. Note that `ArrayList`, in practice is usually still much faster, due to extrem optimizations and benefits of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Linked lists are not designed to be accessed randomly in `O(1)` time. Using an iterator to access it is still `O(n)`.

To understand why, we need to dig into the implementation of `listIterator(int)`:

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
    checkPositionIndex(index);
    return new ListItr(index);
}
```

This methods returns a new `ListItr`, let's see how this is created:

```
    ListItr(int index) {
        // assert isPositionIndex(index);
        next = (index == size) ? null : node(index);
        nextIndex = index;
    }
```

The constructor calls `node`, which is implemented like this:

```
Node<E> node(int index) {
    // assert isElementIndex(index);

    if (index < (size >> 1)) {
        Node<E> x = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) <<<<< HERE!
            x = x.next;
        return x;
    } else {
        Node<E> x = last;
        for (int i = size - 1; i > index; i--) <<<<<< HERE!
            x = x.prev;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Now do you see it? A for loop iterating over the nodes all the way up to the one at index `index`. This means that it is `O(n)`! The speed of getting an iterator increases linearly as the elements in the linked list and your `index` increases.

Answer (score 3):

If your intention is to get the last-but-one element, then since the `LinkedList` implementation is a doubly linked list, then there should be a reference to the tail and the head available to the instance, as well as the size.

This means that a `List.descendingIterator()` would probably be a better starting point, if you have to start at the end, but you are always going to be in O(n) time to index into `LinkedList` structure.

If you are regularly dereferencing by index, you should normally use a random access structure, such as an `ArrayList`.

If you are actually iterating through the list in either direction, then you should return your iterator, not the value.

Comment: Yes, to get the last-but-one element, getting the descending iterator then iterating once, will be O(1).